# Any way to know what music the user is listening to?

Tags: android

I am looking to write an app that is aware of what music the user is listening to (in any other app). Does the Android SDK allow for this?

I know that MediaPlayer objects are generally used, however they seem to be created within the context of the specific app...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [This documentation will be a good start](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html).  Other than that, this question isn't really suited for SO.  If while trying implement something you run into a snag, consider posting then.

Comment: My understanding is that the apps run sandboxed and hence are not able to peek at what another app is doing unless the music app is willing to share that information.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster How is this not suited for SO?  Seems reasonable to ask if there's a way to access music info.

Comment: Okay, I fiddled around with an app called Broadcasts Monitor, none of the popular music apps seem to be broadcasting what they are playing.... Any other ideas?

Comment: @trevor-e He's asking us to do research for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most music apps will send out metadata about songs/tracks that are playing.

You may want to look at using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Okay, I fiddled around with an app called Broadcasts Monitor, none of the popular music apps seem to be broadcasting what they are playing.... Any other ideas?

Comment: You may have to force it to broadcast. Take a look at this tutorial: http://yanuar7199.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/59/

Comment: WOW. I cannot believe this is working, thank you!!!!!